# Using scrapy command "crawl" from django

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a spider (of scrapy) from django and now the problem is, the spider can be crawled only when we are at the top directory(directory with scrapy.cfg). So how can that be achieved?

```
.../polls/managements/commands/mycommand.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import os

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        print ('In run_from_argv')
        self._argv = argv
        return self.execute()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        #os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '/home/nabin/scraptut/newscrawler'
        execute(self._argv[1:])
```

And if i try

```
python manage.py mycommands crawl myspider
```

then I won't be able. Because to use crawl i need to be in the top directory with scrapy.cfg file.. So I want to know, how that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have found the solution myself.

In settings.py I defined:

```
CRAWLER_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'required path')
```

And did the following.

```
from django.conf import settings
os.chdir(settings.CRAWLER_PATH)
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm assuming that you included this code in the settings.py of the django project and not for the scrapy project, but how and where are you able to run the scrapy crawl command? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the working directory, unless you want to use the .cfg which can include default options for the deploy command.

In your first approach you forgot to add the crawler path to the python path and set correctly the scrapy settings module:

```
# file: myapp/management/commands/bot.py
import os
import sys

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from scrapy import cmdline


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Run scrapy"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/mybot')
        os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mybot.settings'
        # Execute expects the list args[1:] to be the actual command arguments.
        cmdline.execute(['bot'] + list(args))
```

Comment: @Nabin help is the description displayed when you run your command with the -h argument.