# Getting the functionality of the scrapy crawl command when running a spider from a script

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a crawl spider within a scrapy project that properly scrapes data from a url and the pipelines the response into a postgresql table, but only when the *scrapy crawl* command is used. When the spider is run from a script in the root directory of the project, it appears that only the parse method of the spider class is being called as the table is not being created upon running the script simply using the python command. I think the problem is that the crawl command has a specific protocol for looking for and calling specific modules in the directory above the spiders package (e.g. the models, pipelines, and settings modules) which aren't being called when the spider is run from a script.

I followed the directions included in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) but they don't seem to address pipelining data after it is scraped. This raises the question of I should even be trying to run a script to run the spider or if I should just use the scrapy crawl command somehow. The problem is, I planned to run the scrapy spider from a django project when the user submits text in a form which lead me to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523281/using-scrapy-command-crawl-from-django), but the provided answer doesn't seem to be addressing the my problem. I would also need to pass the text from the form to be added to the spider url  (I was previously just using raw_input to create the url). How should I properly go about running the spider?
I have the code for the script and the spider below if they are needed. Any help/code provided would be appreciated, thanks.

**script file**

```
from ticket_city_scraper import *
from ticket_city_scraper.spiders import tc_spider 

tc_spider.spiderCrawl()
```

**spider file**

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from ticket_city_scraper.items import ComparatorItem
from urlparse import urljoin

bandname = raw_input("Enter bandname\n")
tc_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"  

class MySpider3(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.ticketcity.com"]

    start_urls = [tc_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/div[@class = "vevent"]'
    def create_link(self, bandname):
        tc_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"  
        self.start_urls = [tc_url]
        #return tc_url      

    tickets_list_xpath = './/div[@class = "vevent"]'

    def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('B')
        price_list = [i.get('P') for i in ticket_info]
        if len(price_list) > 0:
            str_Price = str(price_list[0])
            ticketPrice = unicode(str_Price, "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        else:
            ticketPrice = unicode("sold out", "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price(self, response):
        print "parse price function entered \n"
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        event_City = response.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract() 
        eventCity = ''.join(event_City) 
        loader.add_value('eventCity' , eventCity)
        event_State = response.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text()').extract() 
        eventState = ''.join(event_State) 
        loader.add_value('eventState' , eventState) 
        event_Date = response.xpath('.//span[@class="event_datetime"]/text()').extract() 
        eventDate = ''.join(event_Date)  
        loader.add_value('eventDate' , eventDate)    
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"(\d+)[^-]*$", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/Catalog/public/v1/events/" + json_id + "/ticketblocks?P=0,99999999&q=0&per_page=250&page=1&sort=p.asc&f.t=s&_=1436642392938"
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/span[@class="summary listingEventName"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/div[@class="divVenue location"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/a[@class="divEventDetails url"]/@href')
            #loader.add_xpath('eventDateTime' , '//div[@id="divEventDate"]/@title') #datetime type
            #loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
            ticketsURL = "https://www.ticketcity.com/" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)

def spiderCrawl():
   process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
   })
   process.crawl(MySpider3)
   process.start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Answer Your Question

1. Scrapy Does not differentiate between crawl command and crawl command line( from Script ) execution.

only part (and difference) that you are missing is :

1. scrapy crawl command... always and must be executed from within
   the project directory ..where scrapy.cfg file is located....and if
   you look closely , it contains where the setting file is
   located..and setting file is the central location where all your
   project specific settings are located..like..cache policy ,
   pipelines , header setting, proxy setting  ..etc
   so while using scrapy crawl..all this setting are internally loaded
2. for Scrapy execution from script...you are just providing the
   location of the spider and where it is located and executing it
   without any of your custom setting from settings.py file

for this setting to come into effect..create crawlprocess object with project setting ..

```
settings = get_project_settings()
settings.set('USER_AGENT','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)')
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl(MySpider3)
process.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! Just out of curiosity, where did you find this code? I didn't see it in the docs section for common practices and there are some other things that I would want to do with the spiders.

Comment: It is always there in scrapy doc, not all in one place but it is always been there..and since this project is in beta and public domain..do extensive search , check git bug list , other answer , you will find something useful there..and documentations does have some infor on that ..here  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

Comment: If this other things you want to do is related to spider setting.. Than every parameter that is available for global setting in settings.py file..that you can set and use with the function i mentioned above

Comment: I'm now trying to run multiple spiders in two different projects from the script so I moved the script to the directory just above the root of the project it was in, but now the responses aren't being pipelined into the database tables. Does a change have to be made to the code provided if the script is run outside of the project root?